# Can’t install plugins after updating to WordPress 4.9

Tags: plugins, installation

I’ve just updated a site to 4.9. Before I did that I searched for and installed the UpDraftPlus plugin to make a back up.

Since updating the software if I search for a plugin in the directory I get a message that says ‘No plugins found. Try a different search.’.

If I go to a plugin on the Featured tab and click install I’m also now getting a message that says ‘Installation failed: Installation package not available.’

I’ve tried reinstalling WordPress and deleting the UpDraftPlus plugin but I’m still having the issue.

To get around the issue, I’ve installed a plugin via using FTP, but I’d really like to solve this issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to plugin support?

Comment: Posted to the WordPress forums. It's a puzzle this one, even deactivated all plugins to see if it was a plugin conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Until you get a response from UpDraftPlus support, I would remove UpDraftPlus and just not use it at all. You don't need it. You can create a cron job for different types of backups, whether database, your files, etc.

To list current cron jobs on your server, the command is `crontab -l` and set up a new cron job, its  `crontab -e`.

Setting up a cron job is easy, what you need to learn is the times you need it to run. It would look something like this:

```
MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW /bin/sh command > /dev/null 2 > & 1
* * * * * /bin/sh command > /dev/null 2 > & 1
```